# Ruby on Rails sign up modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

Hello I new to rails and I am trying to make a sign up modal. I am having trouble putting the form elements into the modal. I was wondering how I would go about this. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) rather than implementing the whole authentication yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should look something like this

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Username" %>
   <%= f.text_field :password, placeholder: "Password" %>
   <%= f.text_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: "Password Confirmation" %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply I get a First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty error. Do I need to point the modal to user in routes?

Comment: Yes I am. This is my controller                                                              UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
end

Comment: I misunderstood at first, since you're trying to create a popup modal you'll have to have @ user in whichever view you're in when you press the modal. You can achieve this either using an ajax request or can just pass in @ user = User.new where ever the popup modal can be opened from (I'm assuming just a welcome page?)